# Duplicate a record based on a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, sql-insert

I want to duplicate the record of **step4** with **step3** for each `user_id`.
How can I achieve that?

[image]

**Here is the expected result:**

[image]

**Here is the sample data:**

```
WITH t1 AS (
SELECT 'A' AS interim_id, NULL AS user_id, 'step1' AS step UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS interim_id, NULL AS user_id, 'step2' AS step UNION ALL
SELECT 'A' AS interim_id, NULL AS user_id, 'step3' AS step UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS interim_id, 'B' AS user_id, 'step4' AS step )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `union all`:

```
select interim_id, user_id, step
from t1
select interim_id, user_id, 'step3'
from t1
where step = 'step4';
```

If you want to change the table, then:

```
insert into t1 (interim_id, user_id, step)
    select interim_id, user_id, 'step3'
    from t1
    where step = 'step4';
```